# Can't get to web page hello-kubernetes using KIND, how do I get Kind to bind to localhost:80?

Tags: kubernetes, kind

Due to the nested nature of kind I can't figure out what port to use or how to configure it so that I can just type localhost to get to it.

KIND YAML:

```
kind: Cluster
apiVersion: kind.sigs.k8s.io/v1alpha3
nodes:
- role: control-plane
- role: worker
- role: worker
- role: worker
- role: worker
```

Also tried:

```
kind: Cluster
apiVersion: kind.x-k8s.io/v1alpha4
nodes:
- role: control-plane
  extraPortMappings:
  - containerPort: 8080
    hostPort: 80
    protocol: TCP
- role: worker
- role: worker
- role: worker
- role: worker
```

Getting nodes up: `kind create cluster --config ~/go/kindconfigs/kind-config.yaml`

JOB YAML:

```
# hello-kubernetes.yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: hello-kubernetes
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  ports:
  - port: 80
    targetPort: 8080
  selector:
    app: hello-kubernetes
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: hello-kubernetes
spec:
  replicas: 3
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: hello-kubernetes
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: hello-kubernetes
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: hello-kubernetes
        image: paulbouwer/hello-kubernetes:1.8
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8080
```

running it: `kubectl apply -f ~/go/kindconfigs/hello-kubernetes.yaml`

Comment: Is there any reason why `kubectl port-forward` can't be used? You'd have a more accurate representation this way. If not, `extraPortMappings` are the way to go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Referring from [docs](https://kind.sigs.k8s.io/docs/user/quick-start/#mapping-ports-to-the-host-machine) you need to use `extraPortMappings` to allow the local host to make requests to the hello-kubernetes over port 80

```
cat <<EOF | kind create cluster --config=-
kind: Cluster
apiVersion: kind.x-k8s.io/v1alpha4
nodes:
- role: control-plane
  extraPortMappings:
  - containerPort: 8080
    hostPort: 80
    protocol: TCP
  
EOF
```

The deployment needs to be changed as well

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: hello-kubernetes
spec:
  replicas: 3
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: hello-kubernetes
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: hello-kubernetes
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: hello-kubernetes
        image: paulbouwer/hello-kubernetes:1.8
        securityContext:
          capabilities:
            drop:
              - ALL
            add:
              - NET_BIND_SERVICE
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8080
          hostPort: 80
```

With above configuration you can use `localhost:80` to access the hello-kubernetes application.

Note-1: Without above configuration you could access it via `NODEIP:NODEPORT`

To get `NODEIP`

`kubectl get nodes -o wide`

To get `NODEPORT`

`kubectl describe svc hello-kubernetes`

Node-2: `LoadBalancer` type service only works on supported cloud environments. That's why in a kind cluster running locally on your system you need to use `NODEIP` and `NODEPORT` to access it.

Note-3: You can try [metallb](https://mauilion.dev/posts/kind-metallb/) with kind for making `LoadBalancer` type service work .This should solve `EXTERNAL-IP` pending issue.

Comment: No luck, I already tried variations of that configuration and the IP addresses. FYI, EXTERNAL-IPs are blank only internal IPs show.

Comment: There are some changes needed in the deployment as well..check the updated answer. EXTERNAL-IP will be null as you are not on supported cloud providers

Comment: So I guess I can only have 1 node for this particular case.

Comment: Does kind not support load balancing?